# r [sf] How to enable GEOS support?

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to transform the CRS of polygons that cross the dateline using the `sf` package following the example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295158/r-sptransform-polygon-that-crosses-dateline), but get the warning

Warning message:

```
In CPL_wrap_dateline(x, options, quiet) :
  GDAL Error 6: GEOS support not enabled.
```

which causes the final part of the code to fail:

```
library(sf)
#Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3

point1 <- st_point(c(-179.5, -50))
point2 <- st_point(c(0, -30))
points <- st_sfc(point1, point2, crs = 4236)

points_trans <- st_transform(points, 32621)
circles <- st_buffer(points_trans, 100000)
circles_latlon <- st_transform(circles, 4326)
circles_latlon2 <- st_wrap_dateline(circles_latlon, options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES"))
```

I've looked online on how to enable GEOS support (or perhaps just updating GDAL), but can't find a simple explanation. Any suggestions?

I'm running MACOS 10.13.6; R 3.5.0 (checked also with 3.5.1, but same issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by

1. downloading and installing the updated GDAL and GEOS libraries from [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/)
2. downloading the source file of `sf` from `cran`
3. (re)installing `sf` using `R CMD INSTALL sf_0.6-3.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/unix/bin/gdal-config -with-geos-config=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3B/unix/bin/geos-config'`. Note that I needed to (re)add the .gz extension as apple conveniently hides it.